# How can I get the table format to carry over when sending a table through the excel envelope?

Tags: excel, vba

When I try to email out a table I've made through Excel's envelope, the data and it's placement in the table carries over, but the color, borders, etc. does not.

In this scenario, I'm trying to press the button, have it copy my table range and send it out.I'm looking to get as best of a match as I can in the output. See my code and screenshots below:)

```
Sub DEQACreateAndSend()

' Auto Adjust Sizing based off amount of data given
ActiveSheet.Range("B4:C15").Columns.AutoFit

   ' Select the range of cells on the active worksheet.
   ActiveSheet.Range("B8:C15").Select

Dim cell As Range
Dim rng As Range
Set rng = Range("C7:C14") 'enter your range

On Error Resume Next
    Dim errMsg As String
    For Each cell In rng
    Dim CellString As String
    CellString = cell.Value
    Dim CellLen As Integer
    CellLen = Len(Trim(CellString))

    If CellLen < 1 Then
        errMsg = "Please fill out All required fields!"
    End If
Next cell

If errMsg <> "" Then
    MsgBox errMsg
Else
   ' Show the envelope on the ActiveWorkbook.
   ActiveWorkbook.EnvelopeVisible = True

   ' Set the optional introduction field thats adds
   ' some header text to the email body. It also sets
   ' the To and Subject lines. Finally the message
   ' is sent.
   With ActiveSheet.MailEnvelope
      .Introduction = ""
      .Item.To = Range("C5")
      If IsEmpty(Range("F3").Value) = True Then
        .Item.Subject = Range("C4")
        Else
        .Item.Subject = ActiveSheet.Range("F3").Text + ActiveSheet.Range("C4")
        End If
        .Item.CC = Range("C6")
      .Item.Send
   End With
   ActiveWorkbook.MailEnvelope = False

End If

' Reset Sizing
With ActiveSheet.Columns("C")
    .ColumnWidth = 87
    End With
With ActiveSheet.Columns("B")
    .ColumnWidth = 25.55
    End With
' Set Active Cell to first field
    ActiveSheet.Range("C4").Select


End Sub
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is going to be long so apologies... but it works.

---

The only way I have been able to add a table **with formats** to a outlook email is by converting the excel table to a HTML table first. Then, add the HTML table to your email.

This is the macro to convert a excel table **with formats** to a HTML range. The input here is the range of your table. This will need to be called from a separate macro (that actually builds and sends the email) like so

```
Set EmailTable = Range("??:??")
RangetoHTML(EmailTable)
```

*Notice where the above code is stored in the last macro shared when implementing*

```
Option Explicit

Function RangetoHTML(EmailTable As Range)

''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
'Funciton to convert an excel range to a HTML table

    Dim fso As Object
    Dim ts As Object
    Dim TempFile As String
    Dim TempWB As Workbook

    TempFile = Environ$("temp") & "\" & Format(Now, "dd-mm-yy h-mm-ss") & ".htm"


    EmailTable.Copy
    Set TempWB = Workbooks.Add(1)
    With TempWB.Sheets(1)
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial Paste:=8
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, , False, False
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats, , False, False
        .Cells(1).Select
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        On Error Resume Next
        .DrawingObjects.Visible = True
        .DrawingObjects.Delete
        On Error GoTo 0
    End With

    'Publish the sheet to a htm file
    With TempWB.PublishObjects.Add( _
         SourceType:=xlSourceRange, _
         Filename:=TempFile, _
         Sheet:=TempWB.Sheets(1).Name, _
         Source:=TempWB.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Address, _
         HtmlType:=xlHtmlStatic)
        .Publish (True)
    End With

    'Read all data from the htm file into RangetoHTML
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set ts = fso.GetFile(TempFile).OpenAsTextStream(1, -2)
    RangetoHTML = ts.readall
    ts.Close
    RangetoHTML = Replace(RangetoHTML, "align=center x:publishsource=", _
                          "align=left x:publishsource=")

    'Close TempWB
    TempWB.Close savechanges:=False

    'Delete the htm file we used in this function
    Kill TempFile

    Set ts = Nothing
    Set fso = Nothing
    Set TempWB = Nothing
End Function
```

---

I have no idea if this works with Envelope but I don't consider this to be the best way to send emails from excel anyway. Instead, access the Outlook objects to give you more control. You can use this template (copied directly from a macro I use once a year successfully for last 3 years to send thousands of emails) to get you started.

Notice that the `.HTMLBody` calls the macro above. Wherever you call this macro is where your table will land.

```
Sub Sender ()

Dim OutApp As Object
Dim OutMail As Object
Dim EmailTable as Range
Dim EmailBody as String
EmailBody = "THIS IS YOUR EMAIL BODY"

On Error GoTo FML:
    Set EmailRange = 'INSERT RANGE HERE
    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
        With OutMail
            .to = "To"
            .Subject = "Subject"
            .HTMLBody = "" _
                        & "Hi " 
                        & "<br>" _
                        & EmailBody _
                        & RangetoHTML(EmailTable)

            'Change to .Send to actually send emails
            .Display

        End With
  Exit Sub

FML:
    Set OutApp = Nothing
    Set OutMail = Nothing
    'I usually write to a dynamic cell here denoting failure and pass along any relevant info (.to maybe?)

End Sub
```

---

*the thousands of emails were company internal of course. I am **not** a spammer :)*

Comment: It will likely take you some time to implement this so please try before asking anything.

Comment: The first macro you should copy as-is. The second macro you will need to adjust to fit your needs such as setting the table range, the .to field, . subject field, as well sa the HTML Body